# which.max() by groups but output in the dataframe

Tags: r

There is this data frame given by (an example):

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'Group   Utility
 A      12 
 A      10
 B      3
 B      5
 B      6
 C      1
 D      3
 D      4')
```

I want to use any command (I have been trying iterations of `which.max()` to no avail) to get an additional row in the dataset, say `choice` that is an indicator if `Value` is the max for the group given by `Group` elements. The table would look like:

```
Group Utility Choice
A     12      1
A     10      0
B     3       0
B     5       0
B     6       1
C     1       1
D     3       0
D     4       1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Choice = ifelse(Utility == max(Utility), 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Group Utility Choice
  <fct>   <int>  <dbl>
1 A          12      1
2 A          10      0
3 B           3      0
4 B           5      0
5 B           6      1
6 C           1      1
7 D           3      0
8 D           4      1
```

Comment: Or simply `as.integer(Utility == max(Utility))`, avoiding `ifelse`.

Comment: I did this: `df$choice <- df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Choice = ifelse(Utility == max(Utility), 1, 0))` but it gives an error `Warning message:
In cbind(x[0:(framecol - 1)], cols) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)`

Comment: Remove the `$choice` in the beginning  `df$choice <- etc`. The `mutate(Choice = ...)` already creates a column `Choice`.

Comment: For future viewers, and @Jens & @Rui: Both the solutions with `dplyr` and one-liner base worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nilima that's great. If the answers were useful, you can accept one of them to make future viewers aware that your issue has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner base R solution.

```
df$Choice <- with(df, ave(Utility, Group, FUN = function(x) +(x == max(x))))
df
#  Group Utility Choice
#1     A      12      1
#2     A      10      0
#3     B       3      0
#4     B       5      0
#5     B       6      1
#6     C       1      1
#7     D       3      0
#8     D       4      1
```

Comment: Or `with(df, +(ave(Utility, Group, FUN = max) == Utility))`

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, +(Utility == max(Utility)), Group]
```